# Sorting JSONarray by nested property

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I am trying to sort array of JSON values, but the property to sort is nested within the JSON object. For this example the sort is to be done using data.nested-name.

I tried using https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175221/2053159 but without any success.

```
[
{
name: 'a75',
data: {nested-name:"zz\, Hello// There="}},
{
name: 'z32',
data: {nested-name:"aa\, Hello// There="}},
];
```

expected output ->

```
[
{
name: 'a75',
data: {nested-name:"aa\, Hello There="}},
{
name: 'z32',
data: {nested-name:"zz\, Hello There="}},
];
```

Nested name do contain lot of back and forward slashes and other special characters.
I don't use external libraries, please provide solutions using native JavaScript.

Comment: use `data['nested-name']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming arr is your array, you can sort like so:

```
arr.sort( ( a, b ) => a.data[ "nested-name" ] > b.data[ "nested-name" ] )
```

For higher string comparison accuracy you can use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```
arr.sort( ( a, b ) => a.data[ "nested-name" ].localeCompare(b.data[ "nested-name" ]) )
```

Comment: How can i ignore case sensitivity?

Comment: @NewBee add `toLowerCase()`

Comment: `=> a.data["nested-name"].toLowerCase() > b.data[ "nested-name" ].toLowerCase()` - or use `=> a.data["nested-name"].localeCompare(b.data["nested-name"])`

Answer (score 1):

`array.sort` function takes an optional argument `function(a,b)` which must return `-1, 0, or 1` depending on comparison.
Your data definition contains an error `nested-name:"zz\, Hello// There="`. If you use `-` then you must quote the name.
Working sample is here.

```js
var arr=[
{
name: 'a75',
data: {'nested-name':"zz\, Hello// There="}},
{
name: 'z32',
data: {'nested-name':"aa\, Hello// There="}},
];

var result=arr.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.data["nested-name"] > b.data["nested-name"];
  });
  console.log(result);
```

Comment: How can i ignore case sensitivity?