# How to sort divs in Javascript using classname or id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have div's like below

```
<div class="header">
<div class="name">Name</div>
<div class="status">Status</div>
<div class="message">This is a testing</div>
</div>


<div class="container">
<div class="name">dynamic value comes from DB</div>
<div class="status">dynamic value comes from DB</div>
<div class="Message">dynamic value from DB</div>
</div>
```

I need to sort above structure by clicking Name or Status div header and it should sort data accordingly.

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: so, there's multiple "container" divs? at the moment, there's nothing to sort

Comment: `help me with this` glad to help, it's actually very very easy, what have you done so far besides describing the requirement?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried to use jquery but didn't work.            $('.classname').click(function(){
 var elem = $('#container').find('div').sort(sortClass);
 $('#container').append(elem);
});

function sortClass(a, b) {
 return a.className < b.className;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare a json array of object with key value pair. Eg. [{"name":"xyz", "status":"available"}] Sort it and rebind with dynamic html. Follow below link[Sort json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175093/simple-function-to-sort-an-array-of-objects)