# How to sort a list of objects by a single element which contains multiple properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Here is the list of objects I'm trying to sort.

```
 tcids: [
        {
          name: 'ABD3',
          tcid: '2.A.3.1.1',
        },
        {
          name: 'DDDS',
          tcid: '1.A.3.2.4',
        },
        {
          name: 'DSDG',
          tcid: '2.A.3.2.1',
        },
        {
          name: 'FFF',
          tcid: '1.B.3.2.11',
        },
      ]
```

I want these objects to be sorted by TCID, according to each decimal place. The numbers to the left are the highest priority, and the right are the lowest priority.

For example, 1.A.3.2.4 > 1.B.3.2.11 > 2.A.3.1.1 > 2.A.3.2.1.

I've seen some methods with _.sortBy, but those seem to expect my 'tcid' columns to be deconstructed into some array already. I have not been able to find a percise solution here on SO. Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: All you need is a plain `sort`: `.sort((a, b) => a.tcid.localeCompare(b.tcid));`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175093/simple-function-to-sort-an-array-of-objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple function to sort an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175093/simple-function-to-sort-an-array-of-objects)