# Sort an array of objects lexicographically based on a nested value

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

Using JavaScript, I would like to know how to sort lexicographically an array of objects based on a string value in each object.

Consider:

```
[
 {
    "name" : "bob",
    "count" : true
    "birthday" : 1972
 },
      {
    "name" : "jill",
    "count" : false
    "birthday" : 1922
 },
      {
    "name" : "Gerald",
    "count" : true
    "birthday" : 1920
 }
 ]
```

How can I sort the array alphabetically by name?

The name values are usernames, so I would like to maintain the letter casing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [json sorting question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/json-sorting-question)

Comment: possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-an-array-of-javascript-objects

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
var obj = [...];

obj.sort(function(a,b){return a.name.localeCompare(b.name); });
```

Be aware that this will not take capitalisation into account (so it will order all names beginning with capitals before all those beginning with smalls, i.e. `"Z" < "a"`), so you might find it relevant to add a `toUpperCase()` in there.

You can make it more generic as well:

```
function sortFactory(prop) {
   return function(a,b){ return a[prop].localeCompare(b[prop]); };
}

obj.sort(sortFactory('name')); // sort by name property
obj.sort(sortFactory('surname')); // sort by surname property
```

And even more generic if you pass the comparator to the factory...

Comment: Use `toLocaleUpperCase`/`toLocaleLowerCase` instead of `toUpperCase`/`toLowerCase`.

Comment: This answer no longer holds true (at least on current chrome dev console). `["a", "A", "b", "B"].sort((a,b)=>{return a.localeCompare(b)})` expected to be `["A", "B", "a", "b"]` but returns `["a", "A", "b", "B"]`

Comment: what @user3240644 said. `'aaA'.localeCompare('aAA')` returns `-1` which sorts `aaA` before `aAA` which is incorrect in the case of lexicographic order

Answer (score 3):

This will do it:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response, however I forgot to specify that name is actually a username in my data's case, so I want to maintain the casing that is supplied

Comment: No problem; I've updated my code. Glad it's sorted via @davin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using comparison

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {return a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Comparing_strings

Answer (score 0):

I read in this post [sort array lexicographically in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688028/sort-array-lexicographically-in-javascript) to just use sort directly and not `localeCompare` and this seems to do the trick.

> `localeCompare` does not sort lexicographically.

`'aaA'.localeCompare('aAA')` returns `-1` which sorts `aaA` before `aAA`. In lex, capitals come first, so it should be `['aAA', 'aaA']`

You can do something like this to handle a few cases.

```
export default function sortLex ({ arr, prop, reverse }) {
  let sorted
  if (prop) {
    sorted = arr.sort(sortFactory(prop))
  } else sorted = arr.sort(sort)

  return reverse ? sorted.reverse() : sorted
}

function sort (a, b) {
  if (a < b) {
    return -1
  }
  if (a === b) {
    return 0
  }
  if (a > b) {
    return 1
  }
}

function sortFactory (prop) {
  return (a, b) => {
    return sort(a[prop], b[prop])
  }
}
```

Comment: In your `sort()` function, what happens if a and b are not ordered?