# How to sort an array in lexiographicall order

Tags: javascript, sorting

My goal is to sort the following array [lexiographically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950646/what-is-lexicographical-order#:~:text=Alphabetical%20order%20is%20a%20specific,about%20lexicographical%20order%20on%20wikipedia).
Take the following array:

```
['abc', 'xyz', 'hij', 'def']
```

In the end it should look like this:

```
['abc', 'def', 'hij', 'xyz']
```

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539934/sort-a-array-of-objects-lexicographically-based-on-a-nested-value), which shows how to implement it on an array of objects, but I don't know how to convert the code that it sorts a "normal" array.

Comment: `console.log(['abc', 'xyz', 'hij', 'def'].sort())`

Comment: `a = ['abc', 'xyz', 'hij', 'def'];    a.sort()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As you can see in the ECMAScript Language Specification, lexicographic ordering is the default for strings](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison).

It is, in fact, the default for numbers, too, which is incredibly annoying:

```js
const ns = [4, 18, 8, 6, 1, 15, 7, 16, 17, 9, 13, 2, 3, 11, 12, 14, 20, 19, 10, 5];

console.log(ns.sort());
// [1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 20, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So, you can simply use [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort) with the default comparator, like this:

```js
const strings = ['abc', 'xyz', 'hij', 'def'];

console.log(strings.sort());
// ['abc', 'def', 'hij', 'xyz']
```

As you can see [in the specification for `Array.prototype.sort`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-sortcompare), it delegates to the [*Abstract Relation Comparison* Operation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison), which in step #3 performs a lexicographic compare.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array [sort](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp):

```js
var array = ['abc', 'xyz', 'hij', 'def'];
console.log(array.sort());
```