# Sort JSON with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do i sort this JSON object by first_name?

```
{
    1  :{user_id:1, first_name:"first_name1", last_name:"lastname1", email:"user1@test.com"},
    7  :{user_id:7, first_name:"user2", last_name:"test2", email:""}, 
    72 :{user_id:72, first_name:"testing343", last_name:"", email:""},
    246:{user_id:246, first_name:"aaa", last_name:"ssss", email:""}
}
```

Comment: Objects properties aren't ordered, so you can't sort them.

Comment: @Musa: of course you can. Not directly, but you certainly can sort keynames and do something in order.

Comment: None [of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+sort+json) helped you in any way?

Comment: See : [JQuery: Sorting JSON by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/jquery-sorting-json-by-properties/14949429#14949429)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your *JSON string* is invalid. Clear that up first, you are forced to `eval()` the string in its current form, `JSON.parse()` won't work.

---

Object keys are unordered by spec. You can't statically "sort" key names and freeze them in an object. But you certainly can sort the keynames and operate in that order on their values.

For instance:

```
var json = '{1:{user_id:1, first_name:"first_name1", last_name:"lastname1", email:"user1@test.com"}, 7:{user_id:7, first_name:"user2", last_name:"test2", email:""}, 72:{user_id:72, first_name:"testing343", last_name:"", email:""}, 246:{user_id:246, first_name:"aaa", last_name:"ssss", email:""}}';

json = eval( json );

Object.keys( json ).sort(function( a,b ) {
    return json[a].first_name.localeCompare( json[b].first_name );
}).forEach(function( key ) {
    console.log( json[key].first_name );
});
```

That code assumes the availabilty of an ES5 enabled JS engine or any kind of ES5-shim library.

Comment: the script is sorting and displaying the users correctly. is there a way to sort them permanently? i mean over-write the previous json?

Comment: @JSnewbie: no, not really. Of course you could create an ugly and clunky freezed `json string`, but that won't help you at all. The second you `eval` or `parse` it into an ECMAscript object, key names are random again. Your only choice is to sort it "live" and act on the key/values in order just then.

Answer (score 3):

Write your JSON object like the following:

```
data = [{user_id:1, first_name:"first_name1", last_name:"lastname1", email:"user1@test.com"}, {user_id:7, first_name:"user2", last_name:"test2", email:""}, {user_id:72, first_name:"testing343", last_name:"", email:""}, {user_id:246, first_name:"aaa", last_name:"ssss", email:""}]
```

So that it's now an array. Then you can call `.sort()` on it.

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    var x = a.first_name.toLowerCase(), y = b.first_name.toLowerCase();
    return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to sort an object?

You'll want to loop this object into an array, and then sort the array. http://jsfiddle.net/z2xsC/ For example:

```
//loop into array
var arr = [];
for( var key in data ){
  if( data.hasOwnProperty( key ) ){
    arr.push( data[key] );
  }
}

//now, sort your array
arr.sort( function(a,b) { 
  var nameA=a.first_name.toLowerCase(),
      nameB=b.first_name.toLowerCase();

  if (nameA < nameB){ 
    return -1; 
  } else if (nameA > nameB){ 
    return 1
  } else { 
    return 0
  }
});
```

Comment: the sort algo looks overly complicated, `String.prototype.localeCompare` will do the job.