# How to sort data and measure the length as per key value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need one help.I have some array of data i need to sort the as per key value and measure the length.I am explaining my code below.

```
var response = [{
      day_id:1,
      day_name:"Monday",
      subcat_id:"2",
      cat_id:"1",
      comment:"hii"
}, {
      day_id:1,
      day_name:"Monday",
      subcat_id:"1",
      cat_id:"2",
      comment:"hello"
}
 {
      day_id:2,
      day_name:"Tuesday",
      subcat_id:"3",
      cat_id:"2",
      comment:"hii"
}]
```

Here for `day_id=1` there are two set of data and same for `day_id=2` present.I need to measure length of data set present as per `day_id` `e,g.for day_id=1 length is 2`Please help me.

Comment: sort you have here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208651/javascript-sort-key-value-pair-object-based-on-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `response` and save in an *object* how many times each *id* was seen:

```
var counter = {};
response.map(function(item) {
    counter[item.day_id] = (counter[item.day_id] || 0) + 1;
});
```

Your results are in `counter`:

```
console.log(counter);
// { '1': 2, '2': 1 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @subhra. Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `.map`, use `.forEach` as it doesn't return another array

and the code could be a little cleaner:

```
var counter = {};
response.forEach(function(item) {
    counter[item.day_id] = ++counter[item.day_id] || 1;
});
```