# sort to asc order

Tags: javascript, sorting

This is my array

```
var obj = {
    1: "Principal",
    2: "Vice principal",
    3: "Co-Ordinator",
};
```

I need to sort this array to

```
var obj = {
    3: "Co-Ordinator",
    1: "Principal",
    2: "Vice principal",
};
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery? The `sort()` method is standard JavaScript.

Comment: That's an object, not an array. You can't change the order of object elements.

Comment: Keys that look like integers are always in numeric order.

Comment: Maybe these answers will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208651/javascript-sort-key-value-pair-object-based-on-value

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need jquery to solve this!  Without jquery, your code will have the added benefit of being lighter.

In the code though, "obj" is an unstructured object, not an array, which means you can't sort it.  If you wanted to be able to sort and actually use an array, "obj" would look like:

```
var obj = ["Principal", "Vice principal", "Co-Ordinator"]
```

Then, the indices are implied (principal corresponds to obj[0], vice principal to obj[1], etc.)

To sort alphabetically,  you can then call obj.sort().  This will edit the original array.  More here on the sort method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

You can make this array and apply sorting

```
var obj=[
    {id:1, title:"Principal"},
    {id:2, title:"Vice principal"},
    {id:3, title:"Co-Ordinator"},
];



var sortArray=(obj.sort((a,b)=>{
  let res=0
    if (a.title > b.title) {
    res= 1;
  } else if (a.title < b.title) {
    res= -1;
  } 
  return res;
}));

console.log(sortArray);


Otherwise 
var obj1 = ["Principal", "Vice principal", "Co-Ordinator"];
var obj2=obj1.sort();
console.log(obj2);
```