# getting output of facebook graph api calls in sorted manner?

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way by which i can sort the json received from facebook graph api calls on the basis of value of some particular field?

Comment: Maybe this helps you with sorting JSON files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/jquery-sorting-json-by-properties

Comment: are there any in built functions in javascript that sort a JSON array?