# How to store multiple records in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I wan't to know how store multiple entities in json file (Structure) I will want to find by id functions (JQuery/javascript) and easy sorting (0,1,2...200).

Here my code:

```
{ 
    "id" : 5,
    "name" : "Jemmy overy",
    "data" : {...},
    "link" : "http:...",
}
```

Comment: If you struggle at understanding how to use JSON just look at the quite good [example page](http://json.org/example.html)!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Btw, The answer by Lix below is best if you're looking to pull them out via their index number.

Wrap them in square brackets!

```
[{ 
    "id" : 5,
    "name" : "Jemmy overy",
    "data" : {...},
    "link" : "http:...",
},
{ 
    "id" : 6,
    "name" : "John Smith",
    "data" : {...},
    "link" : "http:...",
}]
```

Comment: This just places the objects into an array.

Comment: I sorta took a leap and figured thats what he was getting at.

Comment: @castis without the brakets ([]), it makes sence, just two different objects, id can also be remobved right, now how do i select the first one just obj[0], obj[1] ?

Comment: `obj[0]` will give you id 5 and `obj[1]` will give you 6 (In this case). The index used in the array has no correlation to the items ID property.

Comment: Thank you, i was not aware I could do this.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the only way I can see to identify the JSON objects in that manner would be to use it's ID property as a key -

```
var a = {
  '5':{ 
    "id" : 5,
    "name" : "AAA",
    "data" : {...},
    "link" : "http:..."
  },'6':{ 
    "id" : 6,
    "name" : "BBB",
    "data" : {...},
    "link" : "http:..."
  },
  ...
};
```

So you access them like an array -

```
a['5']
```

With regard to sorting, I don't think that there is any native way to sort JSON objects, but there are some other posts on the site that provide a helping hand - [Sorting JSON by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/jquery-sorting-json-by-properties)

Comment: Thanks but i was looking for a[5]

Comment: @cez - I don't follow. One is an index and one is a key. The 5th element in the array does not necessarily have to have an id of 5.. It's just in fifth place...

Comment: @CezarisLT You can still cast your id if you have to