# How to write multiple json files in python?

Tags: python, json

First of all, I would like to ask what is a typical format of JSON file with multiple objects?

Is it a list of objects like: `[ {...}, {...} ... ]`?

Second, I tried to store multiple `dict` to a single `JSON` file using python.

I have two JSONs:

```
test_data = {'profile_img': 'https://fmdataba.com/images/p/4592.png',
 'name': 'Son Heung-Min ',
 'birth_date': '8/7/1992',
 'nation': 'South Korea KOR',
 'position': 'M (R), AM (RL), ST (C)',
 'foot': 'Either'}
```

and

```
test_data2 = {'profile_img': 'https://fmdataba.com/images/p/1103.png',
 'name': 'Marc-André ter Stegen ',
 'birth_date': '30/4/1992',
 'nation': 'Germany',
 'position': 'GK',
 'foot': 'Either'}
```

then I did

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:  
    json.dump(test_data, json_file, indent=2)
    json.dump(test_data2, json_file, indent=2)
```

Of course, I would have iterated a list of `dict`s to store multiple `dict`s, but I just did this for now to test if the format is correct. The result `.json` file looks like

**data.json**

```
{
  "profile_img": "https://fmdataba.com/images/p/4592.png",
  "name": "Son Heung-Min ",
  "birth_date": "8/7/1992",
  "nation": "South Korea KOR",
  "position": "M (R), AM (RL), ST (C)",
  "foot": "Either"
}{
  "profile_img": "https://fmdataba.com/images/p/1103.png",
  "name": "Marc-Andr\u00e9 ter Stegen ",
  "birth_date": "30/4/1992",
  "nation": "Germany",
  "position": "GK",
  "foot": "Either"
}
```

It seems pretty weird because there is not `,` between two objects. 
What is the typical way of doing this?

Comment: A list of JSON objects might also be saved as JSON Lines where every line is one object. This way the parser does not need to keep state through the full document. The format you provided without any devider between the objects is hard to parse.

Comment: Not duplicate but perhaps related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487900/how-to-store-multiple-records-in-json

Comment: According to the JSON [specification](http://json.org) you need to put each JSON **object** into a JSON **array** with commas between them. However there is another semi-standard format called [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/) where each JSON object is on a line by itself. The motivation for the latter are the many Unixy line-oriented command=line tools — but it's not strictly in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

You need create an object hold all your date in list first.Then dump this list to file.

```
test_data_list = [test_data, test_data2]

json.dump(test_data_list, json_file)
```