# Dealing with large chunks of data via REST (JSON) API

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, linq, rest

i am writing a wrapper around an API which takes in a couple of inputs and supplies nested JSON data.

Before showing it on UI, i have to order that data by a certain property "Price" which is a decimal  (from high to low).

I am trying to understand

1. What is the most performant way of dealing with this ordering. My UI consumes the same JSON object that comes from the API.

So if i am to order the data from High "Price" to Low

a. do i convert the API output to a strongly-typed list of "Item" objects, 
 b. perform an ordering on the "Price" property 
 c. then convert the list of "Items" back to JSON so that UI can use it.

This just seems to be an overkill to retain this in-memory representation of JSON to perform ordering.

2. If i have a large set of data, how do i stop running out of memory. Again this ties into the answer/solution that will be used in Question 1.

How do i approach this

thanks for your help

Comment: You have no way to get ordered items from your API ?

Comment: Nope. The API only gives a randomly ordered list of JSON data

Comment: So what about that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/sorting-json-by-values

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting. Do you reckon the custom sort method in the link above, will offset the performance hit due to serialisation and deserialisation (if i went with strongly typed objects and used some ".sort" method)?? I am not quite sure

Comment: also does this work for nested jsons?