# How to sort json object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a JSON object like:

```
{
    "resp" : [
        {
            "name" : "s"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "c"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "f"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here, I want to sort the object by `name` values in alphabetical order.
So, it should become this object:

```
{
    "resp" : [
        {
            "name" : "c"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "f"
        },
        {
            "name" : "s"
        }
    ]
}
```

How how can I implement it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/sorting-json-by-values

Comment: Hello! I have edited your code styling, added some explanations and relevant tags. Please, review the changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should sort the array inside the JavaScript object prior to the JSON serialization. A serialized JavaScript object is nothing more than a string and therefore shouldn't be sorted. Take a look at this:

```
var obj = {
    rest: [
        { name: "s" },
        { name: "c" },
        { name: "f" }
    ]
};

function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.name< b.name)
        return -1;
    if (a.name > b.name)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

obj.rest.sort(compare);

JSON.stringify(obj)
```