# sort three items in array when in different order each time

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array containing objects which have a `name` and `type`.

I am trying to always sort the array so the objects are sorted by type as  `home` , `draw`, `away`.

An example of one of the arrays looks like this. The arrays are sent from a backend and are sent in different orders each time. The names are also different each time.

```
var arr = [
  {
    type: 'home',
    name: 'Liverpool Blues'

  }, {
    type: 'away',
    name: 'Manchester Reds'
  },
  {
    type: 'draw',
    name: 'Draw'
  }
];
```

My code looks like this. I thought that draw should get sorted to the middle if home is always pushed to the front, and away is always pushed to the end, although I think there must be an error with how I am sorting the array.

```
return [...selections].sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.type === "HOME") return -1;
    if (b.type === "AWAY") return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/sorting-json-by-values

Comment: Also for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839097/how-to-sort-json-object-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object, which groupes the `type` property by the wanted order.

```js
var array = [{ type: 'home', name: 'Liverpool Blues' }, { type: 'away', name: 'Manchester Reds' }, { type: 'draw', name: 'Draw' }],
    order = { home: 1, draw: 2, away: 3 };

array.sort(function (a, b) { return order[a.type] - order[b.type]; });

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply iterate and position them directly:

```
let arr = [];
selections.forEach(s => {
    if (s.type === "HOME") arr[0] = s;
    if (s.type === "DRAW") arr[1] = s;
    if (s.type === "AWAY") arr[2] = s;
})
```

Then `arr` will be on the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

The order you want is reverse alphabetical (home, draw, away), so reverse sorting on the `type` property will do:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    type: 'home',
    name: 'Liverpool Blues'

  }, {
    type: 'away',
    name: 'Manchester Reds'
  },
  {
    type: 'draw',
    name: 'Draw'
  }
];

arr.sort((a, b) => b.type.localeCompare(a.type));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: the names will be different each time aswell

Comment: @PaulRodriguez I'm sorting based on the `type`, not the `name`.

Comment: that works ! thanks very much. I will give you the green tick when I can. Also, just wondering if there is a way of also doing this, without using alphabetical order

Comment: Take a look at @NinaScholz [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44775546/3558960)