# Sort JSON data when Looping Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I'm using jquery to retrieve data from a local JSON file,
and then looping through the results...

**localjsonfile.json**

```
{
  "CGYacList": [ 
    {
      "Reg": "ZJ920",
      "SqnMarks": 3,
      "TailCode": "QO-A",
      "Notes": "N/A"
    },
    {
      "Reg": "ZJ936",
      "SqnMarks": 7,
      "TailCode": "QO-C",
      "Notes": "N/A"
    },
    {
      "Reg": "ZJ936",
      "SqnMarks": 2,
      "TailCode": "QO-C",
      "Notes": "N/A"
    },
    {
      "Reg": "ZJ936",
      "SqnMarks": 92,
      "TailCode": "QO-C",
      "Notes": "N/A"
    },
    {
      "Reg": "ZJ936",
      "SqnMarks": 3,
      "TailCode": "QO-C",
      "Notes": "N/A"
    }
  ]
}
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
                url: "localjsonfile.json",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {

        var json = $.parseJSON(data);

        for (var i = 0; i < json.CGYacList.length; i++) {            

        alert(json.CGYacList[i].SqnMarks);

        }
```

My question is,
When using `for (var i = 0; i < json.CGYacList.length; i++)` is there a simple way of sorting the results to show `.SqnMarks` in ASC order?

Cheers

Comment: Try if this works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/sorting-json-by-values

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k667L5ns/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply go for custom sorter:

```
json.CGYacList.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.SqnMarks - b.SqnMarks; //reverse it for DSC order
});
```

Comment: Worked a treat, Thanks Arvind

Answer (score 0):

Create an array, insert into the array and sort the array after the for loop:

```
var sqnMarksArr=[];
for (var i = 0; i < json.CGYacList.length; i++) {            
     sqnMarksArr.push(json.CGYacList[i].SqnMarks);
}
sqnMarks.sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. If you want the reverse order flip the -1 : 1.

```
json.CGYacList.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.SqnMarks > b.SqnMarks? 1 : -1;
});
```

Comment: (you don't need the for loop if you're only sorting)

Answer (score 0):

For ASC order :

```
json.CGYacList.sort(function(obj1,obj2){return   obj1.SqnMarks>obj2.SqnMarks});
```

For DSC order :

```
 json.CGYacList.sort(function(obj1,obj2){return obj1.SqnMarks<obj2.SqnMarks});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript sort function or any other Jquery Sorting plugin

```
json.CGYacList.sort(function(a, b){
    return   a.SqnMarks>b.SqnMarks
}
```

Here's a function to sort the array based on any element

```
var sort_by = function(field, reverse, primer){

   var key = primer ? 
       function(x) {return primer(x[field])} : 
       function(x) {return x[field]};

   reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;

   return function (a, b) {
       return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
     } 
}
```

> Credit Goes to  "[Triptych](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43089/triptych)"