# How to sort the json data in array when data is not in ordered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

```js
var data = [
  {
    cid: "59eb15be",
    parentCid: "",
    lv: 1,
    number: "2",
    subject: "Title 2"
  },
  {
    cid: "d7d851ef",
    parentCid: "",
    lv: 1,
    number: "4",
    subject: "Title4"
  },    
  {
    cid: "bd01cc50",
    parentCid: "ae35e67d",
    lv: 2,
    number: "1.1",
    subject: "Title1.1"
  },
  {
    cid: "2d8bd8b0",
    parentCid: "",
    lv: 1,
    number: "3",
    subject: "Title3"
  },
  {
    cid: "7f66a92d",
    parentCid: "ae35e67d",
    lv: 2,
    number: "1.2",
    subject: "Title1.2"
  },
  {
    cid: "ae35e67d",
    parentCid: "",
    lv: 1,
    number: "1",
    subject: "Title1"
  },
  {
    cid: "e7c2dbcc",
    parentCid: "ae35e67d",
    lv: 2,
    number: "1.3",
    subject: "Title1.3"
  },
  {
    cid: "cc784c42",
    parentCid: "ae35e67d",
    lv: 2,
    number: "1.4",
    subject: "Title1.4"
  }
];
 var chapterListDiv = document.getElementById("listSummary");
 var store = document.createDocumentFragment(); //we use this to store temporary orphaned childs
 for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  var node = document.createElement("div");
  node.className = "lv" + (data[i].level || data[i].lv);
        var content = document.createTextNode(data[i].number + "." + " " + data[i].subject);
        node.appendChild(content);  
  node.setAttribute("data-id", data[i].cid); //set a data-id attribute. We need it for the orphaned values.
  node.setAttribute("data-parent-id", data[i].parentCid); //set a data-parent-id attribute. We need it for the orphaned values.
  if (data[i].parentCid == "") //we have a root node
  {
   chapterListDiv.appendChild(node);
  }
  else
  {
   var parent = chapterListDiv.querySelector('div[data-id="'+data[i].parentCid+'"]'); //look for a node with the parent id.
   if (parent) //parent is found
   {
    parent.appendChild(node);
   }
   else
   {
    store.appendChild(node); //temp store the node.
   }
  }
 }
    //final check
    var storeChilds = store.querySelectorAll('div[data-parent-id]');
    if (storeChilds)
    {
        Array.prototype.map.call(storeChilds, function(element){
            var parent = document.querySelector('div[data-id="'+element.getAttribute("data-parent-id")+'"]') ||
                store.querySelector('div[data-id="'+element.getAttribute("data-parent-id")+'"]')
            parent.appendChild(element);
            
        });
    }
```

```css
.lv1 {
    
}

.lv2{
    padding-left: 30px;    
}

.lv3{
    padding-left: 30px;    
}
```

```html
<div id="listSummary"></div>
```

In json data, all item has a "cid" and some of them has "parentCid" which mean it is the child level of it.)

As second level of result

```
1.3. Title1.3
1.4. Title1.4
1.1. Title1.1
1.2. Title1.2
```

This is not order because "1.1" and "1.2" cannot find their parent node when access in loop because their parent node is behind them.
So that is why "1.3" and "1.4" being append  first(parent node is ahead).

Is there any way that can have result correctly like below for second level?

```
1.1. Title1.1
1.2. Title1.2
1.3. Title1.3
1.4. Title1.4
```

Comment: So basically you want sort your data by number and level?

Comment: is it just by number?  e.g. 1.4 is naturally behind 2 and in front of 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/sorting-json-by-values

Comment: maybe you change the value of property `number` to a number without dots and assemble the `number` with the parent `number`.

Comment: I want to sort  my data like 1.1 > 1.2 > 1.3 > 1.4 , not by number but by their position in  data because the number may be words sometimes

Comment: in this case (sort by words) i suggest a separated sorting order property. it makes life easier.

Comment: are the properties `level` and `lv` intended?

Comment: Sorry , that is typo.I correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the data before processing it

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    if ((a.lv | a.level) > (b.lv | b.level))
        return 1;
    else if ((a.lv | a.level) < (b.lv | b.level))
        return -1;
    else {
        if (Number(a.number) > Number(b.number))
            return 1;
        else 
            return -1;
    }
});
```

The `| a.level` is because one of your data points has `level` instead of `lv`.

Answer (score 0):

To order your data by number with hierarchy you should simply use sort function:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.number > b.number
});
```

If you keep this element numbering style it is enough to just sort by this property

I recommended to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/979325/4772988

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parent elements. Then sort the second level elements by converting your string number to floats and subtracting them from each other.

```
var data_sorted = data.filter(function(value, index){
    return value.parentCid != "";
}).sort(function(value1, value2){
    return parseFloat(value1.number) - parseFloat(value2.number);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1wm97vj7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `Array.filter()`, `Array.sort()` and `Array.forEach()`:

```js
var data = [{ cid: "59eb15be", parentCid: "", lv: 1, number: "2", subject: "Title 2" }, { cid: "d7d851ef", parentCid: "", lv: 1, number: "4", subject: "Title4" }, { cid: "bd01cc50", parentCid: "ae35e67d", lv: 2, number: "1.1", subject: "Title1.1" }, { cid: "2d8bd8b0", parentCid: "", lv: 1, number: "3", subject: "Title3" }, { cid: "7f66a92d", parentCid: "ae35e67d", lv: 2, number: "1.2", subject: "Title1.2" }, { cid: "ae35e67d", parentCid: "", lv: 1, number: "1", subject: "Title1" }, { cid: "e7c2dbcc", parentCid: "ae35e67d", lv: 2, number: "1.3", subject: "Title1.3" }, { cid: "cc784c42", parentCid: "ae35e67d", lv: 2, number: "1.4", subject: "Title1.4" }];

// this is the place for your tree generating function
function print(a, l) {
    var ll = l;
    while (ll--) document.write('    ');
    document.write('Computed level: ' + l + '  ');
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (i) {
        document.write(i + ': ' + a[i] + '  ');
    });
    document.write('\n')
}

function getChildren(parent, level) {
    data.filter(function (a) {
        return a.parentCid === parent;
    }).sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.number.localeCompare(b.number);
    }).forEach(function (a) {
        print(a, level);
        getChildren(a.cid, level + 1);
    });
}
document.write('<pre>');
getChildren('', 0);
document.write('</pre>');
```