# Sort divs by price

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have several products. Each has a specific price and I want a button to sort them by the price.

The products are like this on my site:

```html
<div class="product" id="pr_1">Some Content</div>
<div class="product" id="pr_2">Some Content</div>
<div class="product" id="pr_3">Some Content</div>
...
```

I parsed the prices from PHP to JavaScript so I have an JavaScript Object containing all prices and product ids:

```
{12:1, 20:2, 7:3}
```

Currently the key is the price and the value is the product's id.

I want to have them reordered without reload. So JavaScript / jQuery only. I prefer plain JavaScript.

Is there any way to change the order of the `div`s according to the prices of the products?

Comment: What's happen if two products have same price ?

Comment: They should be right next to each other, but it doesn't matter which one is first.

Comment: Ok, but if you use price as key object, it must be unique. Otherwise you get only one product by price.

Comment: I thought it would be better to take the price as a key, so it is easier to sort the products after the price. But I could do it the other way too. So id would be the key and price the value if it will work that way.

Comment: If you are using JQuery take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/sorting-json-by-values) maby it will help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your price HTML in a div :

```
<div id="price_list">

</div>
```

Then, if you can put your prices in a list like this :

```
prices = [
  {id:1, price:12},
  {id:2, price:20},
  {id:3, price:7}
];
```

You'll be able to sort and display with this code :

```
prices.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price);
});
// Your array is sorted

$('#price_list').html('');
prices.forEach(function(entry) {
    $('#price_list').append('<div class="product" id="pr_'+entry.id+'">'+entry.price+' dollars</div>');
});
```

I hope it's fine for you.

If you want a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efupjrk3/)

Comment: Just a side note: the `.sort` prototype doesn't work on `objects`, hence you will have to convert the object to an array if you want to sort it (like the example above, where the list is an `array`).

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by your specification could be done like this [Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/yu8yL6us/3/) (note: list is array, not object).
However, jedema's answer is the way to go.

```
`$(document).ready(function() {
  var list = [[1,19], [2,10], [3,5], [4, 22]];

  list.sort(function(a,b) {
      return a[1] - b[1];
  });

  for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    var $product = $(".parent").find(".product[data-id=" + list[i][0]+"]");
    $(".newparent").append($product);
  }

});`
```