# Sort a mapped JSON alphabetically by a certain key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a (currently static) JSON blob which I am mapping over to output a list item for each object in a React application. However, I want to order the output alphabetically by a specific key.

There is already an answer for the sorting: [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.last_nom < b.last_nom)
    return -1;
  else if (a.last_nom > b.last_nom)
    return 1;
  else 
    return 0;
}

objs.sort(compare);
```

But within my React application, I am not sure how to then sort the mapped array... should I do it as part of the map function? Or separately? Do I chain the sort on after the map?

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "category": "Fruit"
    },
    {
        "name": "Pear",
        "company": "Fruit"
    },
    {
        "name": "Skittles",
        "company": "Confectionary"
    },
    {
        "name": "Milk",
        "company": "Dairy"
    },
    {
        "name": "Brie",
        "company": "Dairy"
    },
    {
        "name": "Twix",
        "company": "Confectionary"
    }
]
```

MAP:

```
return this.fetchProduce().map((item) => (
    <Item key={item.name} item={item} />
));
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This seems to have the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/sorting-json-by-values

Comment: Thank you, how do I merge the sort code with the map code I already have? Do I just chain it?