# How to do Sorting array literal notation data JavaScript or AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to do Sorting array literal notation data  JavaScript or AngularJs 
we have following data , need to do sorting in JavaScript or angular

```
array[0] = {type: 1/1/c30x1}
array[1] = {type: 1/1/c3x2}
array[2] = {type: 1/1/c31x2}
array[3] = {type: 1/1/c30x2}
array[4] = {type: 1/1/c1x2}
array[5] = {type: 1/1/c31x3}
array[6] = {type: 1/1/c30x3}
array[7] = {type: 1/1/c2x3}
array[8] = {type: 10/1/g2}
array[9] = {type: 10/1/x4}
array[10] = {type: 10/1/x3}
array[11] = {type: 10/4/g2}

Output Below 

1/1/c1x2
1/1/c2x3
1/1/c3x2
1/1/c30x1
1/1/c30x2
1/1/c30x3
1/1/c31x2
1/1/c31x3
10/1/g2
10/4/g2
10/1/x3
10/1/x4
```

Comment: What coding have you tried so far? Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/sorting-json-by-values - should solve.