# Json filter the data and sorting them in order

Tags: javascript, json

The json is quite large so I need to be able to filter the data by:

- Name
- country check severity (Critical, Warning, Ok)

and sort the data by:

- name
- created
- modified

I created the json but I'm not sure how to filter them or sorting them.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var showData = $('#results');

    $.getJSON('screenings.json', function (data) {
      console.log(data);

      var results = data.results.map(function (item) {
        return ' Created: ' + item.created + ' Modified: ' + item.modified + ' Name: ' + item.name + ': ' + item.country_check_unknown_severity;
      });

      showData.empty();

      if (results.length) {
        var content = '<li>' + results.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
        var list = $('<ul />').html(content);
        showData.append(list);
      }
    });

    showData.text('Loading the JSON file.');

});
```

Comment: How about using array.filter()?

A description of what it does here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Comment: thanks, good suggestion, could you help?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant sort...not filter. I also think your question is a possible duplicate of this. take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/sorting-json-by-values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting JSON by values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/sorting-json-by-values)

Comment: First, that's not a JSON string. Second, why generate a JSON string, parse into an object and then stringify it back into a string. Generate an object while you're at it.

Comment: Is not a duplication, is probably a similar question, but the content is a bit different.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir would you be able to help?

Comment: @user3699998 Is it necessary to have the `item.name` as key not as value?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I'm not sure really.

Comment: It's better not. I'm working on it

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir really appreciated

Comment: @user3699998 I post an answer bellow. Hope it wasn't so late!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('screenings.json', function (data) {
  // 1 - Generate the objects
  var results = data.results.map(function(item) {
    var o = {};
    o['Created'] = item.created;
    o['Modified'] = item.modified;
    o['Name'] = item.name;
    o['CCUS'] = item.country_check_unknown_severity;

    return o;
  });

  // 2 - Sort the objects
  // the sort function (takes two object compares them depending on the key, and sort order)
  function sortFN(key, ascendant, a, b) {
    var num = ascendant? 1: -1;
    if(a[key] < b[key]) return -num; // return negative if a less than b
    if(a[key] > b[key]) return  num; // return positive if b less than a
    return 0; // return 0 if they are the same
  }

  results.sort(sortFN.bind(null, 'Name', true)); // call sort on objects (explaining bellow)


  // 3 - Generate the strings (generate the strings in any form you want)
  var strings = results.map(function(o){
    var str = "";
    str += "Name: " + o["Name"] + '<br>';
    str += "Modified: " + o["Modified"] + '<br>';
    str += "Created: " + o["Created"] + '<br>';
    str += "CCUS: " + o["CCUS"] + '<br><br>';

    return str;
  })


  // 4 - Show data (show the generated strings)
  showData.empty();
  if (strings.length) {
    var content = '<li>' + strings.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
    var list = $('<ul />').html(content);
    showData.append(list);
  }
});
```

**Explanation for the sort method:** `Array.prototype.sort` takes a callback (function reference) that will pass to it two elements of the array. The callback then compare the two elements passed to it and return `-1` if the first is less than the second, `+1` if the second is less than the first or `0` if the two objects are the same. Now the usual call to sort would be `results.sort(sortFN)` but since `sortFN` expect 4 parameters instead of 2, we manage to do so using `sortFN.bind`. That way is flexible as you can sort the array using any key you want and in any order. So use this:

```
results.sort(sortFN.bind(null, 'Name', false)); // to sort the results array using the key ('Name') in the descending order (false)
// Or...
results.sort(sortFN.bind(null, 'Modified', true)); // to sort it using the key ('Modified') in the ascending order (true)
//...
```

Just note that the sorting of dates could be innacurate as it compares the string not the actual dates. If you want a more accurate way to do it create a function `sortDatesFN` and pass it to `sort` instead of `sortFN`.

**Filtering:**

```
// 1.5 - Filter objects (this is better be before the sort)
// the filter function (check if a string (value) exist inside the string (o[key])
function filterFN(key, value, o) {
    var prop = o[key].toLowerCase();
    return prop.indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1; // return true or false (true if prop includes value, false otherwise)
}

results = results.filter(filterFN.bind(null, "CCUS", "warning")); // will filter all objects that have warning in their CCUS property

// 2 - Sort goes here
...
```

Note that the filtering could be done mor than once. You could filter the result by Name, then for example filter the filtered reuslts again by CCUS.

`filter` takes a callback and give it every item of the array and store it in a new array if that callback returned true. To make filter more flexible (take three parameters instead of one), a `.bind` call is required (the same as for `sort` above). So use this:

```
results = results.filter(filterFN.bind(null, "CCUS", "warning")); // to filter just the object that have "warning" in their CCUS property
// OR...
results = results.filter(filterFN.bind(null, "Name", "s")); // to filter the object that have the character 's' in their Name property.
//...
```

This could be done using a regular expression (`value` will be then a regular expression) and instead of checking `return prop.indexOf(valu...`, it would be `return value.test(prop);`. (If you're familiar with regular expression of course. And it's won't be necessary for the need you mentioned. I just wanted you to know that it can be done in another way).

Comment: thanks for looking at it for me, and explain all, did you try this on plunker at all?

Comment: @user3699998 Yes. Actually I write this code there (using the link you provided). Why? Is there a problem?

Comment: @user3699998 Aaah. I posted just the ajax call (the main hero here hhhh). Other code you'll have to add it yourself.

Comment: is it possible to add a  filter function?

Comment: @user3699998 What do you mean? Where?

Comment: I thing we should Sort the data by: Name, created, modified

Comment: You mean sort by Name and if there is two object with the same name then sort by created and if ...?

Comment: Maybe this will help….

on the list… 

Part 1
1) can you filter all the results by name? 
2) can you filter all results by “Critical”, “Warning” and “Ok” (maybe these could be buttons)
Part 2
3) can you sort your list alphabetically by name?
4) can you sort your list by created?
5) can you sort your list by modified?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134703/discussion-between-ibrahim-mahrir-and-user3699998).

Comment: So say i get back a list of all the “critical” items…. now I want to sort these by name