# sort json by value in descending order

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Have got a JSON node as follows `[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":1,"d":3,"e":2}]` . Need to sort based on value not key in descending order.

Expected output `[{"d":3,"e":2,"b":2,"c":1,"a":1}]`

Comment: Object properties are unordered by nature.

Comment: es2015 has an order, but with exceptions.

Comment: @ankit: solution you tag is based on key sorting . Need sorting based on value

Comment: You still cannot sort the keys of a JSON object based on its value. Either case is same @suhas. Read it properly

Comment: probably this answer is best for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/sorting-json-by-values

Comment: The "duplicate" is a completely different situation. Please read both Qs before voting.

Answer (score 4):

This would require a couple of helper functions (or a library like lodash):

```js
let toPairs = s => Object.keys(s).map(k => [k, s[k]]);
let fromPairs = a => a.reduce((s, [k, v]) => Object.assign(s, {[k]: v}), {});
let cmp = (a, b) => (a > b) - (a < b);

a = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 1, "d": 3, "e": 2};
b = fromPairs(
    toPairs(a).sort((x, y) =>
        cmp(y[1], x[1]) || cmp(y[0], x[0])))

console.log(b);
```

That said, it's usually unwise to rely on object properties being ordered in a particular way.