# How sort all json pairs "key" : "value" by keys?

Tags: java, json

So, I have the next `json`:

```
{
     "massive2":[
         "a",
         "c",
         "b"
     ],
     "key5":"val5",
     "key2":"val2",
     "massive1":[
          "3",
          "4",
          "2",
          "1"
    ],
    "key3":"val3",
    "key4":"val4",
    "key1":"val1"
}
```

How can I sort all pairs by key and all elements in all massives (to the end of `json` tree) in alphabetical, or if it is massive in some other order to get `json` like this:

```
{
     "key1":"val1",
     "key2":"val2",
     "key3":"val3",
     "key4":"val4",
     "key5":"val5",
     "massive1":[
          "1",
          "2",
          "3",
          "4"
    ],
     "massive2":[
         "a",
         "b",
         "c"
     ]
}
```

I don't know beforehand how deep my `json` will be.
Maybe there are some java libraries for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting JSON by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/sorting-json-by-values) (using the answer to sort by keys)

Comment: Deserialize into a sorted map?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let items = {
     "massive2":[
         "a",
         "c",
         "b"
     ],
     "key5":"val5",
     "key2":"val2",
     "massive1":[
          "3",
          "4",
          "2",
          "1"
    ],
    "key3":"val3",
    "key4":"val4",
    "key1":"val1"
};

let data = {};

Object.keys(items).sort().forEach(function(k){
    data[k] = items[k];
});

console.log(data);
```