# Median of an array? Best solution to keep track of median

Tags: javascript

Numbers are randomly generated and stored into an expanding array. How do you keep track of the median?

Ideas:
Array
Binary Tree
Heap

Comment: Most efficient is using two heaps (min and max).

Comment: I wonder you accepted an answer written for Javascript, but removed the [tag:javascrippt] tag!

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/731n4x/java_vs_javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a wide variety of options for programming in general, but since we're working with JS the straightforward way is to simply keep an array and [insert elements in sorted order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21822316/15359157), something like:

```js
class Median {
  arr = []
  insert(i) {
    let l = 0,
      r = this.arr.length
    while (l < r) {
      const m = (l + r) >>> 1
      if (this.arr[m] < i) l = m + 1
      else r = m
    }
    this.arr.splice(l, 0, i)
  }
  get median() {
    const mid = (this.arr.length / 2) | 0
    return this.arr.length ?
      this.arr[mid] : (this.arr[mid - 1] + this.arr[mid]) / 2
  }
}

const m = new Median;
[2, 8, 8, -2, 19].forEach(m.insert.bind(m))
console.log(m.median)
```