# Arranging items of a List

Tags: jquery

I have an Unordered List with me

```
<ul class="uol">
      <li>beta</li>
      <li>gamma</li>
      <li>alpha</li>
</ul>​​​​​
```

One of my co-workers (on a long leave) wrote some code that sorts this list.

```
$(".uol li").sort(asc).appendTo('.uol');

function asc(a, b){
  return ($(b).text()) < ($(a).text());    
}


function desc(a, b){
  return ($(b).text()) > ($(a).text());    
}​
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbpQU/))

I am unable to understand what does the code do, especially this line:

```
$(".uol li").sort(asc).appendTo('.uol');
```

Can anyone please explain this? Also, is this the best way to sort the UOL or is there a better way you know of?

Comment: That is probably the best way. That line selects the list items, sorts them using the named asc function, and then appends them to the ul.

Comment: You could move away from using the undocumented .sort method to instead use the one on Array, however that will make the code less readable.

Comment: I just wrote a detailed explanation of the `sort()` function for another answer. [You can read it here if you want a deep explanation.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423394/algorithm-of-javascript-sort-function/13171179#13171179)

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: ... isn't a really good example included in your question?

Comment: Kevin B, I mean an example using the Array you suggested

Comment: @Aust, looks like a real detailed one. I will go through it later during the day

Comment: Ah, sorry. here you go, less readable, but uses documented methods. `$( $.makeArray($(".uol li")).sort(asc) ).appendTo(".uol");`

Comment: Thanks Kevin B for your answer. Always good to know multiple ways to approach a problem. Can you also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254102/adding-filters-to-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".uol li")`  this gives the all the li items within the `.uol` class. `.sort(asc)` does the sorting in ascending order. `.appendTo('.uol')` . Appends the result into `.uol` class container.

Answer (score 0):

[.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is a javascript function that sorts an array, using the sorting function you pass it.

the function he chose to pass, checks between two adjacent values which one's text has a lower ascii value. the sorter will continue to run this function between every two adjacent values in the array until it is sorted.