# Adding Filters to List

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery remove duplicate li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838845/jquery-remove-duplicate-li)

I have a List which looks like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/UwPTF/

```
<ul class="uol">
      <li>beta</li>
      <li>gamma</li>
      <li>alpha</li>
    <li>beta</li>
    <li>zeta</li>
    <li>BETA</li>            
</ul>
```

I have 2 buttons, one to highlight the items that are duplicate and the other to remove the duplicate items.

I am trying to use the filter function. If you can explain your code, it's highly appreciated.

Comment: Where does that data come from, is it from a database or a script you have access to?

Comment: It's a static list as given in teh example above

Comment: pmandell, not exactly duplicate as I am also looking for code that highlights the duplicate item too + some explanation to help me understand instead of just copying/pasting and finishing the task

Comment: Do you consider the case when checking for dupes?

Comment: yes I am checking for case..so 'BETA' is a duplicate for 'beta'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<ul id="list" class="uol">
  <li>beta</li>
  <li>gamma</li>
  <li>alpha</li>
  <li>beta</li>
  <li>zeta</li>
  <li>BETA</li>            
</ul>

<input id="find" type="button" value="Find" />
<input id="remove" type="button" value="Remove" />​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#find').click(function(){
  $('#list li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).siblings().text().toUpperCase().indexOf($(this).text().toUpperCase()) != -1;
  }).addClass('selecteditems');
});

$('#remove').click(function(){
  var removed = [];
  $('.selecteditems').each(function(i, item){
    if($.inArray($(item).text().toUpperCase(), removed) != -1){
      $(item).remove();
    }
    else{
      removed.push($(item).text().toUpperCase());
      $(item).removeClass('selecteditems');
    }
  });
});​
```

When you click the find button, the filter gets applied to every `<li>` item in your unordered list with the id `list`. It then gets all of the other `<li>` item's, adds their text together into one string and capitalizes it. It then checks if the current `<li>` item when it is capitalized is contained in that string. If it is there, it returns true so it gets the class `selecteditems` added to it.

When you click the remove button, it removes all but the first `<li>` item with the class `selecteditems`, and removes the class from the first `<li>` item.

[**Check it out here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/UwPTF/7/)

---

If you want to be absolutely sure that you are checking against individual items instead of checking against a string of all items, you can change your code for finding to this:

```
$('#find').click(function(){
  $('#list li').filter(function(){
    var sibs = [];
    $.map($(this).siblings(), function(sibling){
      sibs.push($(sibling).text().toUpperCase());
    });
    return $.inArray($(this).text().toUpperCase(), sibs) != -1;
  }).addClass('selecteditems');
});
```

Comment: The remove part of this will only work for one duplicated word, [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/UwPTF/6/) (notice zeta gets removed)

Comment: @billyonecan - Updated answer so now it doesn't. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to compare each item against all others. To have it done efficiently I would have two plain loops over all the list items: in the first loop count how many times each item appears based on its text then in the second loop filter only the items with count greater than 1.

Code would look like this:

```
function GetDupeItems() {
    var oList = $(".uol");
    var allItems = oList.find("li");
    var mapping = {};
    allItems.each(function(index) {
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        if (!mapping[text])
            mapping[text] = 0;
        mapping[text]++;
    });

    return allItems.filter(function() {
        return (mapping[$(this).text().toLowerCase()] > 1);
    });
}
```

Now to mark the duplicates have:

```
GetDupeItems().addClass('duplicate');
```

And it will add a class (e.g. red color) and to hide: (essentially remove from display)

```
GetDupeItems().hide();
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/UwPTF/2/).

Comment: Your example removes the original item too..Eg: Beta has 2 duplicates, but when I click Remove on your example, the original list item gets deleted too

Answer (score 0):

The following would work, making use of the `filter` function.

```
$('#find, #remove').click(function(e) {
  $('.uol > li').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var thisText = $this.html().toUpperCase();

    var count = $('.uol > li').filter(function() {
      return $(this).html().toUpperCase() == thisText;
    }).length;

    if (count > 1) {
      if (e.target == $('#find')[0]) {
        $this.addClass('duplicate');
      } else {
        $('.uol > li').removeClass('duplicate');
        $this.remove();   
      }     
    }

  });
});
```

So basically, loop over each list element, then use the `filter` function to retrieve a count of how many elements in the list have the same text as the current, if that count is greater than 1, give the element the class `duplicate` (note: this is not optimised).

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vPHrc/10/)

Comment: Your example removes the original item too..Eg: Beta has 2 duplicates, but when I click Remove on your example, the original list item gets deleted too

Comment: @TomHodder I've edited my answer in response to your comment, should work fine now.