# How can i sort a multi-dimensional array by Number

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

I want to sort the Array by Id

```
var arr = [{"name":"a", "id":"2"}, {"name":"r", "id":"11"}, {"name":"y", "id":"23"}, {"name":"e", "id":"1"}];
```

I am using following code

```
function compareNum(a,b) {
          if (a.id < b.id)
          {
              return -1;
          }
          if (a.id > b.id)
          {
              return 1;
          }

          return 0;
}
```

Answer Sorting: 1, 11, 2, 23

But I need: 1,2,11,23

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5H3P6/, just subtract one from the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *predefined* [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) JavaScript function:

```
arr = arr.sort(function(current, next){
    return current.id - next.id;
});
```

See a demo online here: http://jsfiddle.net/5J8kk/3/

---

*Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13171179/1505348*

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `parseInt()` to convert each `id` from a string to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Just add some [**parseInt()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and it will work:

```
function compareNum(a, b) {
    if (parseInt(a.id) < parseInt(b.id)) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (parseInt(a.id) > parseInt(b.id)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWvjR/)

--

But actually a simplified version would also work:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.id - b.id;
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWvjR/1/)