# sort object by price using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

- My requirement is sorting objects based on the price.Based on the cash, objects should be sorted.
- Below is the sample data which i consoled and got and showing below.
- By means of consoling full_sky.sort(test); i am getting below data.

---

```
0: Object
id: 1
test: Array[1]
0: Object
fuldata: "xyz"
pat: "xyz"
img: "6E.gif"
nos: "0 - stop"
show_price: 1
sour: "BLR"
tickettype: "e"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
price: Array[1]
0: Object
cash: 44499
total_surcharge: 885
total_tax: 1414
__proto__: Object
length: 1

1: Object
id: 1
test: Array[1]
0: Object
fuldata: "xyz"
pat: "xyz"
img: "6E.gif"
nos: "0 - stop"
show_price: 1
sour: "BLR"
tickettype: "e"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
price: Array[1]
0: Object
cash: 2299
total_surcharge: 885
total_tax: 1414
__proto__: Object
length: 1

2: Object
id: 1
test: Array[1]
0: Object
fuldata: "xyz"
pat: "xyz"
img: "6E.gif"
nos: "0 - stop"
show_price: 1
sour: "BLR"
tickettype: "e"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
price: Array[1]
0: Object
cash: 3399
total_surcharge: 885
total_tax: 1414
__proto__: Object
length: 1
```

Output should be something like this

```
1: Object
id: 1
test: Array[1]
0: Object
fuldata: "xyz"
pat: "xyz"
img: "6E.gif"
nos: "0 - stop"
show_price: 1
sour: "BLR"
tickettype: "e"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
price: Array[1]
0: Object
cash: 2299
total_surcharge: 885
total_tax: 1414
__proto__: Object
length: 1

2: Object
id: 1
test: Array[1]
0: Object
fuldata: "xyz"
pat: "xyz"
img: "6E.gif"
nos: "0 - stop"
show_price: 1
sour: "BLR"
tickettype: "e"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
price: Array[1]
0: Object
cash: 3399
total_surcharge: 885
total_tax: 1414
__proto__: Object
length: 1

0: Object
id: 1
test: Array[1]
0: Object
fuldata: "xyz"
pat: "xyz"
img: "6E.gif"
nos: "0 - stop"
show_price: 1
sour: "BLR"
tickettype: "e"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
price: Array[1]
0: Object
cash: 44499
total_surcharge: 885
total_tax: 1414
__proto__: Object
length: 1
```

Comment: what is `test` in `full_sky.sort(test)`

Comment: response from api getting in the form of json , assigning the data to variables and pushing into full_sky.push(test);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be done like:

```
   var myObject= [
          { Cash: 323, Text: "abc" },
          { Cash: 4567, Text: "zxc" },
          { Cash: 83456, Text: "fgg" },
          { Cash: 72, Text: "hjk" },
          { Cash: 1, Text: "tyu" },
          { Cash: 543, Text: "bgt" },
          { Cash: 245, Text: "ljj" },
          { Cash: 68798, Text: "mnu" }
   ];

   // Sort ascending
   myObject.sort(function (a,b){
         if (a.Cash < b.Cash)
            return -1;
         if (a.Cash> b.Cash)
            return 1;
         return 0;
   });

   // Sort descending
   myObject.sort(function (a,b){
         if (a.Cash < b.Cash)
            return 1;
         if (a.Cash> b.Cash)
            return -1;
         return 0;
   });
```

Just have to pick the "Cash" property of the required object and sort it. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of operations u can try using the lo-dash library. ([http://lodash.com/docs](http://lodash.com))

Please check the docs for more. SortBy function should solve your problem [Lo-Dash SortBy](http://lodash.com/docs#sortBy)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't ensure an order in objects and therefore sorting objects directly is not possible here. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14208661/1083314) for better understanding on why and the relevant documentation. In your case, I would recreate a `key-value` pair list with the `key` as the `cash` attribute of your object and then sort that array directly modifying the `sort` function.

Assuming your initial array of objects is called `list1`, you could do:

```
 For simplicity:
 list2 = [];
 for (i=0;i<list1.length;i++){ list2.push({'key': list1[i].price.cash,'val' : list1[i]});}

 //list2 would be populated as :
 list2 = [{key:44499, val: Object},..];

 //To sort the list2 based on ascending order of cash

 list2 = list2.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.key - b.key;
 });


 //In your case,you could accomplish this directly as well doing just :
 list1.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.cash.price- b.cash.price;
 });
```

Here, I have overwritten the `sort` function a little bit to take care of the order. A [relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423394/algorithm-of-javascript-sort-function) on how the sort function works in javascript might be of further help.