# How .sort () work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Array.sort implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation)

I want to know how `.sort()` works in JavaScript. What algorithm does it use?

```
function sortNumber(a, b) {
   return a-b;
}

var n = ["1", "5", "40", "2", "9", "3"];
document.write(n.sort(sortNumber));
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting for you. Please use the preview pane next time.

Comment: "How `.sort()` working" in what way? It sorts. The precise algorithm is probably implementation-defined. What else do you want to know?

Comment: hi tomalak ,thanks for doing formatting. I want to know which algo is used on .sort() function.

Comment: Then your question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation).

Mozilla uses merge sort, Webkit uses selection sort, and IE is closed-source so hard to tell.

The language specification states no requirement on what algorithm an implementation uses, and your code shouldn't really care about it too much.

Answer (score 0):

Number of comparisons for 100 element test array:

Safari 5 - 541
Opera 11.10 - 586
Firefox 4 - 601
IE 9 - 618
Chrome 9 - 783

And for 1000 element test array:

Safari 5 - 8700
Firefox 4 - 8998
Opera 11.10 - 9137
IE 9 - 11055
Chrome 9 - 11536

It does not describe an algorithm but still shows some interesting data.

Answer (score -1):

in Firefox 4 the elements are converted into Numbers and sorted this way.
In your case this is ascending order.

I didn't test it in other browsers so far.

Comment: Elements are not converted into numbers. Elements don't change. Expression `a-b` calculates numerical result, that's all.