# Javascript sort array function performance

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how the built-in JS function `array.sort()` functions internally?  I mean does it change strings to numbers....etc

```
var keys = new Array();
keys.sort();
```

Comment: btw, `new Array` is evil, use `[]` literal syntax instead.

Comment: The algorithm is specified [here](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.4.11). Apart from that I'm not sure what else you want to know.

Comment: To answer the question: No, `.sort` will not change any element values, **unless** you specify a function which modifies the input. eg: `keys.sort(function(x,y){x.moo=1337; y.cowsay="bar";})`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [MDN docs for sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting
>   them to strings and comparing strings in lexicographic ("dictionary"
>   or "telephone book," not numerical) order. For example, "80" comes
>   before "9" in lexicographic order, but in a numeric sort 9 comes
>   before 80.

Refer to the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation) as to what algorithm is being used.

Comment: +1. Reading this just saved me from some hard to track bugs later in production. Too bad one can only favorite the question, and not the answers.