# Understanding Javascript .sort parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

I am having trouble understanding why the following function sorts the string numerically (in the third section of the code) .

```
var myArray = [10, 44, 32, 100, 0, 44, 3, 4];
console.log(myArray.toString()); // 10, 44, 32, 100, 0, 44, 3, 4 --> unsorted

myArray.sort();
console.log(myArray.toString()); // 0,10,100,3,32,4,44,44 --> sorted like strings

// this is what confuses me:
myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
return a - b;
});
console.log(myArray.toString()); // 0,3,4,10,32,44,44,100 --> sorted numerically
```

**Specifically**:

1. How do `a` and `b` get populated?
2. Why is does subtracting `a - b` sort the numbers in numerical order?
3. How do all the numbers get sorted into proper order if the function is only examining 2 numbers at a time? (i.e. `a` and `b`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What really happens in Javascript Sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588921/what-really-happens-in-javascript-sort)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.sort` takes an optional parameter, which should be a function.

`.sort` then calls that function repeatedly, passing it a pair of values from the array (the `a` and `b` parameters). The function then returns a value which is interpreted like so:

- If the returned value is less than 0, then `a < b`
- If the returned value is greater than 0, then `a > b`
- If the returned value is exactly 0, then `a == b`

Using this, `.sort` figures out the order of the items using whatever sorting algorithm the browser has been programmed to use.

In the absence of a sorting function, `.sort` will sort the items as strings - this is just an arbitrary point of the design. Ideally you should be passing a function to be used whenever you want to `.sort` things, as is the case here where the function forces the values to be compared as numbers.

Comment: how does it know when to stop? does it compare every number to every other number?

Comment: @jon You may want to read up on how [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) work.

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason (and I should find documentation) the default behavior for `Array.prototype.sort` is to sort by string, not numerically.  That means that you have to *define* numeric sorting behavior.

1. *How do `a` and `b` get populated* - Welcome to the world of functional programming.  The array is iterated over internally and the callback function is called with a (first element) and b (second element) until the elements are exhausted.  You don't have to worry too much about this, just know that that is what happens.
2. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on this is pretty clear, fortunately.  If the return value of the callback is less than 0, `a` has a lower index than `b`.  If `0` is returned, keep them at the same index relative to other elements.  If a positive value is returned, `b` has a lower index than `a`.  That means that `a - b` is guaranteed to work properly for numerical sorting.  ***However***, you will run into trouble with this callback function if there are any non-numeric elements.  Only use it if you know for a fact that the array contains only numeric elements.
3. This does a simple insertion sort and actually does not go two at a time, but will backtrack if `b` happens to be less than `a`.  You can examine this behavior by adding a `console.log(a,b)` to the sort callback method.

Comment: I would be *very* surprised to learn that the `.sort()` method were an insertion sort and not either a quicksort (most likely) or merge sort (unlikely but it'd probably be better).

Comment: i tried putting `console.log(a,b)` inside the function and it didn't work... I'd really love to see it work through the problem step my step. what am I doing wrong: https://gist.github.com/jonamar/4974057 ?

Comment: @jon think about what `return` does.  It breaks out of the function right.  If you call `return` and *then* `console.log`, the latter will never be reached, right?  Put `console.log` before `return`.

Comment: @jon tracking what a sorting algorithm is doing by logging from the comparison function is going to be confusing, at best.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript `.sort()` function always sorts arrays as if their contents were strings, by default.  That's just what it does. It's basically that the default sort function does a `.toString()` on each value.

[Here's a link to the specification.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4) It's very confusing, but the key is towards the end of the description of the sorting comparison process.

Comment: but why does the second part work to make it sort them numerically -- i.e. how does it work?

Comment: @Jon because your function treats the arguments as if they're numbers, not strings. The key is that you're doing that subtraction.