# Why does Array.sort compare certain value pairs twice sometimes?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm using this Javascript code to view the order in which array elements are compared when the `sort` method is invoked.

```
function log(text)
{
    document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
}

[5, 4, 3, 2, 1].sort(function (a, b) {
    log("comparing " + a + " and " + b);
    return a - b;
});
```

I'm not surprised to see that different browsers produce different outputs because of diverse implementations.
What I cannot realize is why IE and Opera sometimes compare the same pair of values twice in succession. That doesn't make any sense to me. Sorting arrays looks like such a basic language feature I'm probably missing something here. Can someone explain this behavior?

Here are my test results:

## IE 9 and 10

- **comparing 4 and 5**
- **comparing 4 and 5**
- comparing 3 and 5
- comparing 3 and 4
- comparing 2 and 5
- comparing 2 and 4
- comparing 2 and 3
- comparing 1 and 5
- comparing 1 and 3
- comparing 1 and 2

## Firefox

- comparing 5 and 4
- comparing 5 and 3
- comparing 4 and 3
- comparing 2 and 1
- comparing 5 and 1
- comparing 3 and 1
- comparing 3 and 2

## Chrome

- comparing 5 and 4
- comparing 5 and 3
- comparing 4 and 3
- comparing 5 and 2
- comparing 4 and 2
- comparing 3 and 2
- comparing 5 and 1
- comparing 4 and 1
- comparing 3 and 1
- comparing 2 and 1

## Opera

- comparing 5 and 4
- comparing 2 and 1
- **comparing 3 and 1**
- **comparing 3 and 1**
- comparing 3 and 2
- comparing 5 and 1
- comparing 4 and 1
- comparing 4 and 2
- comparing 4 and 3

And the proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/Sd9ph/

Comment: You can probably find the answer buried in the [implementation details for sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation).

Comment: That's depend on sort algorithm used in javascript engine implemented by the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know the details, since their implementations are not open source.

Yet, Opera seems to use some a merge sort where the merge phase includes comparing the range boundaries (to do a more efficient concatenation instead of merging item-per-item - when possible). In the minimal case, one of the ranges has only one item in it - which will then be compared twice if it cannot just be prepended. It *could* use an optimisation, but it won't happen that often, so it wasn't worth it apparently.

You can check the behaviour [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd9ph/2/) with three-item-arrays. Example for `[3,2,1]`:

```
3 2 1

[3][2 1] // divide

[3][2 1] // compare (and exchange)
    ^ ^
[3][1 2] // compare upper with lower boundary (would concat if possible)
  ^^
[3][1 2] // but they're overlapping, so let's merge…
 ^  ^
1 [3][2] // …by comparing smallest items from each set
   ^  ^
1 2 3
```

Example for `[2,1,4,3]`, with concatenation:

```
2 1 4 3

[2 1][4 3] // divide

[2 1][4 3] // and sort sub-arrays
 ^ ^  ^ ^
[1 2][3 4] // compare boundaries
    ^^
1 2 3 4    // uh, we're done already!
```

This concatenation will make the mergesort faster for (at least partly) already-sorted arrays.

Internet Explorer in contrast does a classical insertion sort. I'd assume that it first tests whether the array is already sorted - which fails at the first comparison, 4 is not >= 5. Then it inserts 4 before 5, 3 before 5 and 4, 2 before 5 and 4 and 3, and since 1 lacks a comparison with 4 it seems it uses a kind of binary search for that.

Comment: Uh, I had only looked at Opera - sorry. Extended my answer with a detailed explanation of my theory and what IE seems to do.

Comment: Ok, your explanation about the IE checking if the array is already sorted makes perfect sense. I still don't get the double comparison in Opera. When I perform a regular divide and conquer sorting over [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] I get comparisons in this order: (5, 4), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3). What's this sorting algorithm in Opera called and how is it supposed to do a more efficient concatenation?

Comment: It looks like a normal [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) (uh, did I forgot to state that?) to me, but with an optimized merge algorithm. It starts by dividing (into [5,4][2,3,1], then the latter in [2][3,1]) and sorting them (latter first), but then it does *only* merge them item-by-item (repeatedly choosing from the smallest two items of the two sets) *if the two ranges overlap*. If they don't, they just can be concatenated - saving a lot of compare operations.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that comparing the boundaries only happens for the two adjacent items - fixed the answer, and included better example.