# Sorting an number array

Tags: javascript

When I want to sort an array, using sort() function , it is giving an alphabetically sorted array. 
Eg.

```
var a=[9,10,1];
a.sort();
```

I'm getting `a = [1,10,9]`

So, as per the suggestions I used another function

```
function sortfunction(x, y){
    return (x - y) //causes an array to be sorted numerically and ascending
}
```

and then used

```
a.sort(sortfunction);
```

to get the right result.

Can anyone explain in detail, how this works?

Comment: Isn't it explained in detail in the Javascript specification?

Comment: @Barmar—a reference would be handy—[ECMA-262§15.4.4.11](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version fails as they're compared like they're strings (`"9"` is greater than `"10"`), known as a *lexicographic* sort.

The custom comparator function is called with `a` and `b` being members of the array.

Depending on what is returned, the members are shifted. If `0` is returned, the members are considered equivalent, if a negative number, then `a` is *less than* `b` and the inverse if it's a positive number.

If you want to visualise this, you can always log `a` and `b` to the console and observe how they're compared (and note how there is never any redundant comparisons made).

This is all backed by a sorting algorithm, which is left up to the implementation to choose.  Chrome, for example, uses [different algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/236534/31671) depending on the type of members.

Comment: How does it work when `x - y` will always be `true` if x and y are not the same?

Comment: When is `x - y` ever true if they're numbers?

Comment: The comparison function is not boolean. It's tri-state: negative, 0, or positive.

Comment: Oh `.sort` depends on negative or positive values. I thought it receives a Boolean instead. I totally forgot about it and I just read the spec.

Comment: so , sortfunction return either 0.+ve or -ve.
and these are passed as a argument to a.sort(),
what will be the first argument to a.sort()?
will that be difference of first two elements of the array?

Comment: 5-2 is positive, 2-5 is negative. one flips position, one doesn't.