# Clear explanation of .sort() behavior for this case

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

```
alert("0123456789".split("").sort(function(){return .5-Math.random()}).join(""));
```

This is probably one of the shortest ways to generate a 10-digit number in JavaScript that contains 10 digits from 0 to 9 in the randomized order. Example: 7205169483.

```
split("")//OK, it splits by chars because of empty separator
.sort(function(){return .5-Math.random()})
.join("")//joins with empty string as a separator
```

Why doesn't `{return Math.random()}` work?

How many times `.sort()` is executed - ten or one?

Comment: Because `Math.random` gives you a number between 0 and 1.

Comment: Did you look at the definition of the `sort` function ? What is expected from the callback ?

Comment: Why downvote? A doubt is a fare doubt, might be the user would have missed some thing. As some might not always be perfect.

Comment: Agree, question looks decent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it correct to use JavaScript Array.sort() method for shuffling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802/is-it-correct-to-use-javascript-array-sort-method-for-shuffling)

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said in the comments by @elclanrs, `sort` expects a callback function that will take two elements `a` and `b` and compare them. This function must return a negative number if `a < b`, `0` if `a == b` and a positive number otherwise.

The function sort will be called a number of times that depends on the implementation of the sorting algorithm. You can find more information [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation).

In your example, `0.5 - Math.Random()` will return a negative, or a positive number, because Math.Random() returns a value between 0 and 1.