# Sorting algorithm in Gecko/Trident/Presto

Tags: javascript

What algorithms are used in Gecko/Trident/Presto engines, when I call standard javascript array's method sort(functionSort)?

Comment: In Gecko, it's merge-sort since [this issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=224128) has been fixed.

Comment: Still I wonder shouldn't we close this post as duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation). What's important is that ECMAScript standard doesn't describe any specific algorithm, leaving the choice up to browser vendors - and those guys aren't particularly committed to a specific algo. What should happen with this thread if (when) someone decides to change the sort implementation in some browser covered by it?

Comment: Thank You! I will read this!:)