# Sorting of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
arr=[-37.507,-3.263,40.079,27.999,65.213,-55.552];
arr.sort();
```

and the result is

```
arr=[-3.263,-37.507,-55.552,27.999,40.079,65.213]
```

Can any one help me what logic that "sort()" function is doing?
Please explain me why "arr.sort();" gives the above result.?
And other questions doesn't have the exact answer which explains what i am getting here.

Comment: You can have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation

Comment: @RajKumar Thank you, But by using this function i couldn't able to get correct sorted array, U could see that in my question . Please explain it.

Comment: re: "other questions doesn't have the exact answer"; yes they do. The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1063027/660921) on this question says: "By default the sort method sorts elements alphabetically"; which is exactly the problem you have, and the description is exactly the same as the answer you accepted on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

array.sort sorts strings, if you want to sort numerically, you need a comparison-function:

```
array.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

Comment: Thank you @MBaas, But you can see that the result is wrong which is in my question could you explain it please?

Comment: The results is correct, pls. check here: http://jsfiddle.net/evpt2wfr/

Answer (score 0):

The default sort function treats each item as a string. Lexicographic order is not the same as numerical order. For numerical sorting, do this:

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
```

The argument to `sort()` is a function that returns a negative number only if `a` comes before `b`.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a>b) return 1;
    if (a<b) return -1;
    if (a==b) return 0;
});
```