# Why would this example iterate through an array to sort, instead of using the .sort() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm going through some basic array challenges on w3.

Here is the task given:

Write a JavaScript program to sort the items of an array.

Sample array : var arr1 = [ 3, 8, 7, 6, 5, -4, 3, 2, 1 ];
Sample Output : -4,-3,1,2,3,5,6,7,8

Here is their given solution:

```
    var arr1=[-3,8,7,6,5,-4,3,2,1];  
var arr2=[];  
var min=arr1[0];  
var pos;  
max=arr1[0];  
for (i=0; i<arr1.length; i++)  
{  
        if (max<arr1[i]) max=arr1[i];  
}  

for (var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)  
{  
        for (var j=0;j<arr1.length;j++)  
        {  
                if (arr1[j]!="x")  
                {  
                        if (min>arr1[j])   
                        {  
                                min=arr1[j];  
                                pos=j;  
                        }  
                }  
        }  
        arr2[i]=min;  
        arr1[pos]="x";  
        min=max;  
}  
alert(arr2);
```

---

This is what I came up with... :

```
var arr1 = [ -3, 8, 7, 6, 5, -4, 3, 2, 1 ];

arr1.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});

console.log(arr1);
```

Why does it seem to me that their solution is so much more "convoluted"? Is it necessary to add their solution to protect against a specific use case?

Comment: No, but is it good to know how to wrap your head into how to do it without using native methods? Might be why it was done that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort an array, always use built-in functions rather that writing your own. It takes away the pain of useless debugging and, actually, re-inventing the wheel.

`.sort()` is absolutely OK.

Moreover, not only the long solution is "convoulted", it's `O(n^2)` whist the native sort is [usually faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation).

And it's doing some weird stuff with the `'x'` value and uses `==` instead of `===`, so it looks not so good at all.

Comment: yeah. I think I've lost trust in their "solutions".  Any recommendations on better code challenges / drills. Aside from writing your own programs (which, I'm doing)?

Comment: @someoneHere probably, as mentioned by charlietflm the point was to learn how to write a simple sort yourself but it does not take away any other issues. As far as I know, codescool.com has nice tutorials

Comment: Yeah. I feel that should have been included in their objective, though . I can write working code and understand for loops, etc. Working more towards writing more clean/ maintainable code at this point.