# Explanation of arrayObj.sort( [sortFunction] )

Tags: javascript, sorting

I know about sorting arrays, but I have the question I'm aching to find out.

For instance:

```
var array = [9,3,0,-2,15];
```

So, let's sort it:

```
function sortFunction(a, b){

  if(a < b) return -1; // or any number that less than zero, but why?
  if(a > b) return 1; // or any number that above zero, but why?
  if(a = b) return 0; // but why?

  // I know it may be easier a - b, I've written it for clarity

}

array.sort(sortFunction); //so we'll get correct result
```

How to understand why it has to return -1, 1, and 0 for sorting array?

P.S. Sorry if question seems stupid, I haven't found the answer in Google.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) and it explains it pretty clearly

Comment: I was misunderstood(

Comment: @Jarvis — Just saying you were misunderstood helps nobody. You need to clarify your problem.

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> - If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to an index lower than b, i.e. a comes first.
> - If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different
>     elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this
>     behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating
>     back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.

There are three outcomes, so three possible return values.

Comment: I've read it, I've already known this info, I think, I was misunderstood