# Understanding consistently wrong behavior with sort()

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I have the following code:

```js
let arr = [];

for (i = 14; i <= 31; i++) {
  let d = "2018-08-" + String(i);
  arr.push({
    date: d
  });
}

arr.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);

console.log(arr);
```

1. I know `sort()` is supposed to be used only with numbers
2. I know that comparing strings with `-` is a bad idea
3. I already localized and fixed the original bug in my code, but...

There is something that fascinates me about this buggy code: the result.

Subtracting a string from another string gives `NaN`, so I'd expect the array to stay the same (`14, 15, 16, 17... 31`), or maybe to get completely flipped (`31, 30, 29, 28... 14`).

Instead, the actual (consistent) result is

[image]

I'm very curious about knowing why exactly `sort()` is outputting that sequence of strings. Why `31`, `15` and `23` get moved, and why do they get moved to those particular positions?

Comment: If the sort is unstable, this could be an artifact of the algorithm. What happens if you do away with the subtraction entirely and just have the comparator function return a constant?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Sure, but even if that was some sort of unexpected behaviour, shouldn't it be random?

Comment: What you are seeing is the order things are being compared. Since the sort implementation isn't dictated by the standard we can only assume that whatever algorithm is being used looks at the objects in this order. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation

Comment: @MarkMeyer I'm not really sure that explains it, because, as Carcigenicate suggest, replacing the entire subtract by a constant (true or false), I get completely different results. Is the problem was the sorting algorithm, I should get the same result, or maybe just the same number of "out of order" elements at the same positions.

Comment: @alexandernst I'm actually getting the same results as you if I just return NaN in the comparator. It seems to depend specifically on the length of the list, and the type of constant returned. If you alter either, then the order changes.

Comment: This could be reduced down to simply: `var arr = []; for (var i = 14; i <= 31; i++) arr.push(i); arr.sort((a, b) => "fubar"); console.log(arr)`. I get the same results with this. I'd post a fiddle, but JS fiddle is derped on mobile.

Comment: The spec mentions that `If comparefn is not undefined and is not a consistent comparison function for the elements of this array (see below), the behaviour of sort is implementation-defined.` and later defines that `comparefn` must not return a value `v` where `Type(v) is Number, and v is not NaN` to be consistent. Given you do not provide a consistent sort function the behavior is entirely up to the specific engine implementation, which should be irrelevant to all programs. In other words, fix your `comparefn` and be done with it ;)

Comment: @plalx that should really be an answer.

Comment: @alexandernst see edited answer with snipper from V8 code that shows why the order (at least in chrome) is the way it is when returning a constant value from the compare function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is probably easier to understand with a simpler array.

For example:

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

arr.sort(() => NaN)

console.log(arr)
```

In chrome this returns an array order like: `[0,11,2,3,4,5,1,7,8,9,10,6]`.

This is peculiar, but if you look at the implementation of sorting in the V8 code you will find a mix of quicksort and insertion sort. In fact if will recursively call quicksort until the arrays being recursed on have a length less than 10, then it will switch to insertions sort.

The way quick sort chooses the pivot explains the behavior you're seeing. Here's a snippet with the slightly truncated code from V8:

```js
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];

function comparefn(a,b){
    return NaN
}
function InsertionSort(a, from, to) {
    for (var i = from + 1; i < to; i++) {
      var element = a[i];
      for (var j = i - 1; j >= from; j--) {
        var tmp = a[j];
        var order = comparefn(tmp, element);
        if (order > 0) {
          a[j + 1] = tmp;
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
      a[j + 1] = element;
    }
  };

function QuickSort(a, from, to) {
    var third_index = 0;
    while (true) {
      // Insertion sort is faster for short arrays.
      if (to - from <= 10) {
        InsertionSort(a, from, to);
        return;
      }
      third_index = from + ((to - from) >> 1);
      
      // Find a pivot as the median of first, last and middle element.
      var v0 = a[from];
      var v1 = a[to - 1];
      var v2 = a[third_index];
      var c01 = comparefn(v0, v1);
      if (c01 > 0) {
        // v1 < v0, so swap them.
        var tmp = v0;
        v0 = v1;
        v1 = tmp;
      } // v0 <= v1.
      var c02 = comparefn(v0, v2);
      if (c02 >= 0) {
        // v2 <= v0 <= v1.
        var tmp = v0;
        v0 = v2;
        v2 = v1;
        v1 = tmp;
      } else {
        // v0 <= v1 && v0 < v2
        var c12 = comparefn(v1, v2);
        if (c12 > 0) {
          // v0 <= v2 < v1
          var tmp = v1;
          v1 = v2;
          v2 = tmp;
        }
      }
      // v0 <= v1 <= v2
      a[from] = v0;
      a[to - 1] = v2;
      var pivot = v1;
      var low_end = from + 1;   // Upper bound of elements lower than pivot.
      var high_start = to - 1;  // Lower bound of elements greater than pivot.
      a[third_index] = a[low_end];
      a[low_end] = pivot;

      // From low_end to i are elements equal to pivot.
      // From i to high_start are elements that haven't been compared yet.
      partition: for (var i = low_end + 1; i < high_start; i++) {
        var element = a[i];
        var order = comparefn(element, pivot);
        if (order < 0) {
          a[i] = a[low_end];
          a[low_end] = element;
          low_end++;
        } else if (order > 0) {
          do {
            high_start--;
            if (high_start == i) break partition;
            var top_elem = a[high_start];
            order = comparefn(top_elem, pivot);
          } while (order > 0);
          a[i] = a[high_start];
          a[high_start] = element;
          if (order < 0) {
            element = a[i];
            a[i] = a[low_end];
            a[low_end] = element;
            low_end++;
          }
        }
      }
      if (to - high_start < low_end - from) {
        QuickSort(a, high_start, to);
        to = low_end;
      } else {
        QuickSort(a, from, low_end);
        from = high_start;
      }
    }
  };

// run it
QuickSort(arr, 0, arr.length)

console.log(arr)
```

If you look at this, especially the way the pivot is chosen and when it switches to insertion sort, you will see why the results are ordered the way they are.

When the compare function always returns NaN, all the `if`s in the code are bypassed that look like this:

```
var c12 = comparefn(v1, v2);
if (c12 > 0) { /* etc /*}
```

Meaning the whole sort reduces to the smaller:

```js
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];

function comparefn(a,b){
    //console.log(a, b)
    return NaN
}

 function QuickSort(a, from, to) {
    var third_index = 0;
    while (true) {
      // Insertion sort is faster for short arrays.
      if (to - from <= 10) {
        return;
      }
       third_index = from + ((to - from) >> 1);
      // Find a pivot as the median of first, last and middle element.
      var v0 = a[from];
      var v1 = a[to - 1];
      var v2 = a[third_index];
      
      a[from] = v0;
      a[to - 1] = v2;
      var pivot = v1;
      var low_end = from + 1;   // Upper bound of elements lower than pivot.
      var high_start = to - 1;  // Lower bound of elements greater than pivot.
      a[third_index] = a[low_end];
      a[low_end] = pivot;
      partition: for (var i = low_end + 1; i < high_start; i++) {
        var element = a[i];
      }
      if (to - high_start < low_end - from) {
        QuickSort(a, high_start, to);
        to = low_end;
      } else {
        QuickSort(a, from, low_end);
        from = high_start;
      }
    }
  };
QuickSort(arr, 0, arr.length)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Excellent answer! This deserves +1000 upvotes. Thank you for taking the time to explain this mystery properly!