# NodeJS Faster Execution on Repeated Function Calls

Tags: node.js

I was writing a JavaScript implementation of merge sort in NodeJS, since the native V8 `sort` function uses quick sort, which is less efficient than merge sort in its worst case. In order to the test the performance, I made an array of 10000 elements, pre-sorted (worst-case for quick sort) and timed how long it took to sort this list with both functions. In a single execution, the native `sort` function takes about 16 milliseconds, where my implementation takes about 9 milliseconds. However, when executing both 100 times, the native `sort` takes about 2.1 milliseconds on average, and mine takes about 4.3 milliseconds. Here is my code:

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');

function merge(a, b, func) {
    const array = new Array(a.length + b.length);
    let aIndex = 0;
    let bIndex = 0;
    while(aIndex + bIndex < array.length) {
        if(aIndex >= a.length || func(a[aIndex], b[bIndex]) > 0) {
            array[aIndex + bIndex] = b[bIndex++];
        } else {
            array[aIndex + bIndex] = a[aIndex++];
        }
    }
    return array;
}

function mergeSort(list, func) {
    if(list.length <= 1) {
        return list;
    }
    const half = list.length / 2;
    return merge(mergeSort(list.slice(0, half), func), mergeSort(list.slice(half), func), func);
}

function time(func, iters) {
    let sum = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
        let startTime = performance.now();
        func();
        sum += performance.now() - startTime;
    }
    return sum / iters;
}

const arr = [...Array(10000).keys()];
const sortFunc = (a, b) => a - b;
console.log("JavaScript built-in sort execution time, one iteration:")
console.log(time(() => arr.sort(sortFunc), 1)); // ~16
console.log("Manually implemented merge sort execution time, one iteration:")
console.log(time(() => mergeSort(arr, sortFunc), 1)); // ~9
console.log();
console.log("JavaScript built-in sort average execution time, 100 iterations:")
console.log(time(() => arr.sort(sortFunc), 100)); // ~2.1
console.log("Manually implemented merge sort average execution time, 100 iterations:")
console.log(time(() => mergeSort(arr, sortFunc), 100)); // ~4.3
```

Why is it so much faster when executed repeatedly than only once, and why is this improvement more pronounced for the native `sort` function?

EDIT: I was able to make my algorithm more efficient by tracking array indices instead of using the `slice` method. My code now consistently beats v8's native `sort` when used on pre-sorted arrays, but loses on randomized arrays, as expected. Here is that code, for those interested:

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');

function merge(a, b, func) {
    const array = new Array(a.length + b.length);
    let aIndex = 0;
    let bIndex = 0;
    while(aIndex + bIndex < array.length) {
        if(aIndex >= a.length || func(a[aIndex], b[bIndex]) > 0) {
            array[aIndex + bIndex] = b[bIndex++];
        } else {
            array[aIndex + bIndex] = a[aIndex++];
        }
    }
    return array;
}

function mergeSortRec(list, func, start, limit) {
    if (limit === 1) {
        return [list[start]];
    }
    const half = limit / 2 | 0;
    return merge(mergeSortRec(list, func, start, half), mergeSortRec(list, func, half + start, limit - half), func);
}

function mergeSort(list, func) {
    return mergeSortRec(list, func, 0, list.length);
}

function time(func) {
    let startTime = performance.now();
    func();
    return performance.now() - startTime;
}

const sortFunc = (a, b) => a - b;

console.log();
console.log("--- Sequential array ---");
console.log();
const sequenceArr = [...Array(10000).keys()];
console.log("JavaScript built-in sort execution time, one iteration:");
console.log(time(() => sequenceArr.slice(0).sort(sortFunc)));
console.log("Manually implemented merge sort execution time, one iteration:");
console.log(time(() => mergeSort(sequenceArr, sortFunc)));
let sum = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const array = sequenceArr.slice(0);
    sum += time(() => array.sort(sortFunc));
}
console.log("JavaScript built-in sort average execution time, 100 iterations:");
console.log(sum / 100);
sum = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    sum += time(() => mergeSort(sequenceArr, sortFunc))
}
console.log("Manually implemented merge sort average execution time, 100 iterations:");
console.log(sum / 100);

console.log();
console.log("--- Randomized array ---");
console.log();
const randomArrays = new Array(101);
for(let i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
    randomArrays[i] = new Array(10000);
    for(let j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
        randomArrays[i][j] = Math.random() * 5000 | 0;
    }
}
console.log("JavaScript built-in sort execution time, one iteration:");
console.log(time(() => randomArrays[100].slice(0).sort(sortFunc)));
console.log("Manually implemented merge sort execution time, one iteration:");
console.log(time(() => mergeSort(randomArrays[100], sortFunc)));
sum = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const array = randomArrays[i].slice(0)
    sum += time(() => array.sort(sortFunc));
}
console.log("JavaScript built-in sort average execution time, 100 iterations:");
console.log(sum / 100);
sum = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    sum += time(() => mergeSort(randomArrays[i], sortFunc))
}
console.log("Manually implemented merge sort average execution time, 100 iterations:");
console.log(sum / 100);
```

Comment: This is how V8's JIT compiler works. "hot" sections of code get micro-optimized based on a widening amount of assumptions the compiler can make about the function based on how it's called. Also, native functions have access to more tightly optimized code than non-native functions do.

Comment: By the way, V8 `sort()` method does not use quicksort, it uses [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which _is_ highly optimized for pre-sorted arrays.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Though I double checked, and according to the source code (found [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/js/array.js#L239) thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37245185/10601037)), it looks like v8 uses quick sort for arrays larger than 10 elements and insertion sort when the array has 10 or fewer elements.

Comment: [This source](https://mobile.twitter.com/mathias/status/1036626116654637057?lang=en) claims that the latest version of V8 will now use Timsort, as it used to. A stable sorting algorithm is not guaranteed by the ECMAScript specification, but it has been a sore spot for a few years that at least the implementors are willing to address.

Comment: Huh, strange. I wonder why that's not in their repository yet. Thank you for letting me know!