# JavaScript Algorithms and JavaScript Engines

Tags: javascript, algorithm, v8, spidermonkey, javascript-engine

Is **algorithms** for JavaScript functions on different **JavaScript engine** varies?

I run `Array.sort()` in **Chrome** and **Firefox** browser, and two of them perform differently for the same code.

*Are they used different algorithms for the same code?*

Answer (score 1):

All that's guaranteed by the specification is a *non-stable* in-place sorting method.

So yes, different implementations are allowed to use different algorithms, and because the specification does not guarantee a stable algorithm, different non-stable algorithms will result in different orders if your array values evaluate as equal, which is any falsy return value from the compare function you pass to [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: which algorithms are used by v8 and spider monkey?

Comment: @JobinMathew always Google before you ask. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation) easily came up.