# Why the first item in native javascript function sort() - is the second in my array?

Tags: javascript

When I was trying to understand how the sort(i mean native js) function works (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
and used their function:

```js
let numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(numbers);
```

I added a console.log, but the first element was the second:

```js
 let numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
    numbers.sort((a, b) => console.log('a - is - '+ a));
    console.log(numbers);
```

Why?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now that arrow function in the second example is returning `undefined`.  Do `numbers.sort((a, b) => {console.log('a - is - '+ a); return a - b;});`

Comment: See [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28889450/691711).

Comment: You added the `console.log` but removed the comparison and don't actually return anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation

Answer (score -1):

You neglected to return anything (other than `undefined`) from your logging version which is why it is failing to sort. You also only log one of the values.

```js
let numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
numbers.sort((a, b) => {
  console.log('a: ' + a + ' - b: ' + b);
  return a - b
});
console.log(numbers);
```

Taking a look at [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.sort) doesn't explicitly state why the items are passed in a seemingly reversed order and seems to be open for interpretation by JS engine implementors. As such I might expect to see different behaviour with other JS engines although it's just as likely that they all implement this the same way.

Comment: but the first element (a) is not 2 but 4

Comment: @Nina The `sort` method decides what params its callback gets; there's no "first" or "second", there's `a` and `b`, and the user doesn't decide what references they get.